# How to skip execution of test case from the Hooks in cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have to skip execution of the test case @bannerVerificationSMMDView only when the viewPort is Large

```
@Before
    public void beforestartUp(Scenario scenario) throws IOException {    
     boolean runTest = true;
        if (viewPort.contains("LARGE")) {
            System.out.println("for Scenario " + scenario.getName() + " tagname are");
            List<String> tags = (List<String>) scenario.getSourceTagNames();
            for (String tagName : tags) {
                if (tagName.contains("bannerVerificationLView"))
                    runTest = false;
            }
            try {
                Assume.assumeTrue(runTest);
            } catch (AssumptionViolatedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   }
```

Not sure why, but exception is not getting caught

Comment: Which version are u using? junit or testng?

Comment: i am using Junit

Comment: What is the cucumber version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throw a `AssumptionViolatedException` to skip the execution of scenario.

```
@Before(value="@bannerVerificationSMMDView")
public void before(Scenario scenario) {

    if(viewPort.contains("LARGE"))
        throw new AssumptionViolatedException("Skipping as view is LARGE");

}
```

If you are on cucumber version 3 plus, you can use a `@BeforeStep` annotation instead, keep everything else same. This will allow you to run any previous steps in the scenario and if condition is not met then skip the rest of the steps in the scenario

Comment: I tried similar approach, updated code in the question but still exception is not getting caught. Cucumber version 1.2.4

Comment: No need for the Assume part just throw the exception explicitly when the LARGE condition is met. Do not catch any exception..

Comment: In the Junit report shows test case is fail. Any way we can show it is skipped or pass in this case ?

Comment: Just tried it on 1.2.5 and it shows skipped in junit report. can u add the runner options and report output to the initial question.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. It is skipping test with 1.2.5 version

Comment: [org.junit.AssumptionViolatedException;](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/AssumptionViolatedException.html)

Comment: I get an error and the exception does not stop the scenario running: "A handler for AfterHookEvent failed: Skipped or Undefined result status are not valid for hooks"