# How to skip scenario from feature file

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have 4 scenarios and a background in my feature file .

Background :

Scenario1 
Scenario2 
Scenario3 
Scenario4

I need to skip scenario4 from my feature file executing.

How can i achieve it?

Comment: Skip at runtime? Otherwise give the scenario 4 a tag like 'wip' and exclude 'wip' tag in the runner options.

Comment: @Grasshopper Yes At runtime only

Comment: You can use this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51017800/how-to-skip-execution-of-test-case-from-the-hooks-in-cucumber/51019064#51019064

Comment: Cant be at feature file level  like adding tag @skip ?

Comment: I am not sure i understand what u r saying... Can u clarify.

Comment: I meant , as we have feature file and we have scenarios in that . Can we skip the scenario ?
Like if we add @Ignore and it should skip the particular scenario.

Comment: U mentioned u wanted to skip at runtime. Cucumber does not allow runtime addition of tags. There is a plan of 'wip' tags in cucumber 4, though not sure if it has anything to do with runtime